# How do Spring Data repositories know where your database is located?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have been looking at the Spring Framework guides (specifically the database access guide), and I am having trouble comprehending parts of them. In the [MongoDB guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb), it goes over creating a model, creating a `MongoRepository`, and interacting with the data.

But nowhere does it cover how the application knows where you MongoDB server. For example, if I am using a hosted MongoDB, how does Spring Data know what my connection string along with my credentials are? How can I configure this?

Comment: Great question! Manish's answer is correct. I've created [a ticket](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-mongodb/issues/11) in the guide's repository to improve it to mention how the connection is actually obtained.

Comment: For quick reference, the ticket raised as a result of this question suggests the guide should refer to http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-mongodb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial you have referred to uses [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/).  The `@SpringBootApplication` annotation enables the application to auto-discover JPA and MongoDB enabled repositories.

Auto-configuration for MongoDB is provided by the class [MongoAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.java), which in turn uses the class [MongoProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoProperties.java) for locating the MongoDB server to connect to.  By default, this points to a MongoDB instance running on `localhost` port `27017`.

As the tutorial says, for manual control over MongoDB repositories, use the `@EnableMongoRepositories` annotation.

Comment: Also see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html (and look for the section "# MONGODB" with keys spring.data.mongodb.*) for the available properties that you can define in Spring Boot application.properties/application.yml files without switching to @EnableMongoRepositories

Comment: Excerpt..

# MONGODB (MongoProperties)
spring.data.mongodb.host= # the db host
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017 # the connection port (defaults to 27107)
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost/test # connection URL
spring.data.mongodb.database=
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=
spring.data.mongodb.grid-fs-database=
spring.data.mongodb.username=
spring.data.mongodb.password=
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=true # if spring data repository support is enabled